# Change of state of a Material Button with different background colour in Fragment which switches fragments under condition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to do the following:
I have an activity_main.xml which has a Fragment Container View inside of him. There, I have different fragments to display.
The First Fragment has a Spinner, an Edit Text and a Material Button. The button, when clicked, changes this Fragment with another. The condition I want to consider is that if the Spinner has a non-empty item selected (string, in this case) AND the Edit Text has inside its text the previous item's, then the Material button is enabled (changing background colour) AND clickable, with the result of changing Fragment. But the button never changes state (remains grey in this case) and remains disabled and unclickable even if conditions seems to be met. What am I overseeing? Maybe I am using View Binding erroneously?

Here is the code I am referring to:

MainActivity.kt

```
import...

import com.example.MyAppExample.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.MyAppExample.databinding.FragmentFirstPageBinding
import com.example.MyAppExample.databinding.FragmentSecondPageBinding


private  lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private  lateinit var page1_binding: FragmentFirstPageBinding
private  lateinit var page2_binding: FragmentSecondPageBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val mainView = binding.root
        setContentView(mainView)

        page1_binding = FragmentFirstPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val page1_view = page1_binding.root

        val firstFragment = FirstPage()

        val spinner1 = page1_binding.spinner
        val edtxtPIC = page1_binding.edittextPICmodel
        val continuebuttonpage1 = page1_binding.continue1Button


        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {

            replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, FirstPage())
            commit()

        }

    }


    fun navigateToPage2() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(binding.fragmentContainerView.id, SecondPage())
            .addToBackStack(null) // Optional: Add transaction to back stack for back navigation
            .commit()
    }

    fun spinnerItems(dynamicSpinner: Spinner){

        page1_binding.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                Log.v("item", parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as String)
                updateButtonState()

            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                updateButtonState()

            }
        }


    }

    fun editText1Behaviour(){

        page1_binding.edittextPICmodel.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                updateButtonState()
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            }

        })

    }

    fun updateButtonState(): Int {

        val selectedSpinnerItem = page1_binding.spinner.selectedItem?.toString()
        val editTextContent = page1_binding.edittextPICmodel.text.toString()

        if (!selectedSpinnerItem.isNullOrBlank() AND editTextContent.contains(selectedSpinnerItem)) {
            val occurrences = editTextContent.split(selectedSpinnerItem).size - 1
            return occurrences

        } else {
            return 0
        }

    }

}<
```

FirstFragmentActivity

```
import...

import com.example.MyAppExample.databinding.FragmentFirstPageBinding
import com.example.MyAppExample.databinding.FragmentSecondPageBinding


class FirstPage : Fragment( ) {

    private  lateinit var firstPage_b: FragmentFirstPageBinding
    private  lateinit var secondPage_b: FragmentSecondPageBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }


    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        firstPage_b = FragmentFirstPageBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return firstPage_b.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val button1enabled = false

        val dynamicSpinner: Spinner = firstPage_b.spinner as Spinner
        val items: Array<String> =
            arrayOf("PIC10", "PIC12", "PIC16", "PIC17", "PIC18", "PIC24", "PIC32")
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            requireActivity(),
            R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            items
        )
        dynamicSpinner.adapter = adapter


        val edittextPIC: EditText = firstPage_b.edittextPICmodel

        firstPage_b.edittextPICmodel.addTextChangedListener {

            (activity as MainActivity).editText1Behaviour()

        }

        firstPage_b.spinner.onItemSelectedListener {

            (activity as MainActivity).spinnerItems(dynamicSpinner)
        }


        if((activity as? MainActivity)?.updateButtonState() == 1) {

            firstPage_b.continue1Button.isEnabled = true
            firstPage_b.continue1Button.isClickable = true
            firstPage_b.continue1Button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

            firstPage_b.continue1Button.setOnClickListener {

                (activity as MainActivity).navigateToPage2()

            }
        }

        else {

            firstPage_b.continue1Button.isEnabled = false
            firstPage_b.continue1Button.isClickable = false
            firstPage_b.continue1Button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)

        }
    }




private fun Spinner.onItemSelectedListener(value: () -> Unit) {

}
}
```

FirstFragment xml:
How I have set the Button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/continue_1_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="@string/continue_button"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```